# How can I add an SSL client certificate/key globally in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, security, ssl, certificates

I have a web server which requires a client certificate to establish an SSL connection (`SSLVerifyClient require` in apache). In firefox or chrome, I simply import the .p12-file containing my certificate in PKCS 12 format in the tab "Your Certificates", and this works like it should.

Now I want to use other applications, which afaik don't have the functionality to provide a client SSL certificate themselves (e.g. nautilus). I guess that there has to be a system-wide location where I can store my client certificate, but the only thing I find when googling is where to store CA certificates.

So my question is how can I add SSL client certificate / key files (either .p12 or .crt and .key I guess) so that they are used systemwide?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this as well. As fara as I can tell, nautilus or gnome does not offer an obvious way to include client certificates, or even custom certificate authorities.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install your cert under: **/etc/ssl/certs**. It would need to have the .crt extension. Your application would need to be configured to look in the **/etc/ssl/certs** path for the certs, but it should work. I have Fetchmail configured to pull reference **/etc/ssl/certs**.