# How to establish a webdav connection with TLS client certificate authentication in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, webdav, tls

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233242/how-do-i-establish-a-webdav-connection-in-gnome-3) answer works nice for establishing webdav or webdavs connections with nautilus.

However, when I try this on a webdav share secured with a self-signed TLS client certificate authentication, I get:

First:

```
The signing certificate authority is not known.
Certificate information:
....
Are you really sure you would like to continue?
```

And after I click on yes:

```
...Unhandled error message: HTTP Error: Error performing TLS handshake: A TLS fatal allert has been received.
```

...and I am never asked for a client certificate.
I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and would **preferably like this to work with Nautilus.**
I need instructions including the installation of the client certificate (and the CA authority).

PS: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268637/how-can-i-add-an-ssl-client-certificate-key-globally-in-ubuntu) question seems related (not identical), but has no answer either.

Comment: whats the CA signing this certificate ?

Comment: @amiaschanner It is the company I work for (so I would have to install the CA.crt file also). I have not done this. However, in firefox the CA.crt and the client certificate work as they do on win with WebDrive  (just mentioning that to clarify that there is no problem with the certificates)

Answer (score 2):

One solution that worked, is using [davfs](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2).

### Installation

Install davfs

```
sudo apt-get install davfs2
```

### Configuration

then copy the certificate from the CA (in pem format) to /ect/davfs2/certs and the client certificate (in .p12 format) to /ect/davfs/certs/private and modify the configuration file e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf
```

by uncommenting (removing the #) the lines trust_ca_cert and clientcert and adding the full paths to the respective certificates e.g.

```
trust_ca_cert         /etc/davfs2/certs/ca.cert.pem
#servercert
clientcert            /etc/davfs2/certs/private/xxx.yyy.com.p12
```

save the file and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> in nano) and make sure the clientcert has the correct permissions

```
sudo su
chmod 0600 /etc/davfs2/certs/private/xxx.yyy.com.p12
exit
```

### Optionally configure credentials file

You can use a credential file located at:

```
/etc/davfs2/secrets
```

This way you will not have to enter your password each time. The file has good examples of its syntax, which I will not replicate here.

### Usage

To mount the filesystem run

```
sudo mount -t davfs -o uid=bruni,gid=users https://serveraddress /home/bruni/mountpoint
```

### Drawbacks

The problems with this solution are:

1. The website offers links in the form
   davs:// which do not work with the above scenario

(We solved this serverside by providing links in the form file://

1. Freefilesync returns the following error when I try to synchronize with a folder mounted as above:

   Cannot set directory lock for "/path/to/mountpoint".

   Cannot write file "/path/to/mountpoint/sync.ffs_lock".

   Error Code 13:Permission denied (open)

**update** To mitigate this, I have switched to rsync.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a self signed certificate you will need to ensure that *BOTH* ends have the CA public cert installed.

This typically doesn't work in the same way for all packages as some don't make use of the central cert store.

Heres some instructions on install root CA certs in ubuntu
[How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

Comment: The Server side definitely has the CA public cert installed. On the client side I followed the instructions of the accepted answer to the link you provided, but I continue to receive the same response. This would imply that Nautilus does not use the central cert store or that I did not follow the instructions correctly (don't think that as I saw the certificate during installation).

Comment: I have also installed these certificates with double clicking in nautilus (hoping that this installs in the cert store that nautilus itself uses)

Comment: you might need to logout and back in again to pick up changes, shouldn't need a restart though

Comment: This does not seem to suffice, I receive the same response